# Cannot install latest packages from apt in WSL (Ubuntu)

Tags: apt, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been trying to install python `3.10.4` from `apt` but it always keeps installing python `3.8.2`. I ran `sudo apt update` and the output is following:

```
Hit:1 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x focal InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Fetched 336 kB in 2s (146 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
```

The `ppa` listed above looks like the official ones (I am a linux newbie, I couldn't spot if anything was wrong here). Now if I run `apt policy python3`, I still get python `3.8.2`, not the latest version which is `3.10.4`.

```
python3:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.8.2-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
     3.8.2-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

The problem also seems to occur for other packages. For example, the latest stable `fzf` version is `0.30.0`, but running `apt policy fzf`, I get a much older version `0.20.0`:

```
fzf:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.20.0-1
  Version table:
     0.20.0-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
```

The package version in `apt` might not be the absolute latest one so far I am concerned, but still should it lag by that much? How would I ensure that the packages I install from `apt` are the latest ones, if not then at least close to the latest version?

Comment: the packages from `apt` are very much not necessarily the latest versions. They are maintained by entirely different people than the software itself. If you want the latest version you can compile it from source yourself.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software - relevant for WSL and any Ubuntu version really

Comment: Agree with @ThomasWard - I think [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software) answers your question.  If so, let us know by accepting it in the header above.  If not, let us know by editing the question with more details.  Thanks!